# Parametrization of the cuspidal cubic

Tags: algebraic-curves

I didn't understand why the method works fine to find the parametrization of the cuspidal curve:

[image]

I didn't understand why finding these intersections points will give me the whole curve.

thanks

Comment: do you know what are the level curves for $x^3-y^2=0$?

Comment: @janmarqz no I don't know, maybe $y=\lambda x$?

Comment: check[ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=implicitplot+x%5E3-y%5E2%3D%3D0 ]

Comment: @janmarqz every point meet some line which passes through the origin, hence we can parametrize the curve by this intersection, am I right?

Comment: the level curve $x^3-y^2=0$ intersect the lines $y=\lambda x$, yes, sample [ http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%5B+%7Bx%5E%283%2F2%29%2C-x%5E%283%2F2%29%2C+x%7D+%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C0%2C1.2%7D ]

Comment: @janmarqz thank you for your help

Comment: do forget to upvote me :D

Comment: @janmarqz it's done :)